# Application crash at launch while downloading from test flight

Tags: ios, xcode7, itunes, archive, testflight

After submitting the application for review I got a rejection saying that application crash on launch, I tested the same build through test flight and its crashing at launch but the same application works when running through Xcode in all devices irrespective of OS versions.

How can I debug the issue with the Testflight build? Anything missing while creating an archive for upload?

**iTunes Rejection Details**

*Performance - 2.1
We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
Next Steps
Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch without crashing.
Resources
For additional information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and Supporting IPv6-only Networks.
For a networking overview, please see About Networking.*

Comment: Connect device to mac and open logs, in Xcode -> window -> devices -> and there device log

Comment: I found the issue, it's not related to IPv6. Actually, in my project, there are some third-party frameworks which are not enabled for bitcode and in project setting I set bitcode to yes so while downloading from Test Flight app crash on launch and not for other build taken from Xcode.

Set Bitcode to YES only your all third-party supports bitcode else set Bitcode to NO in your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue of iPv6 from iTunes, because of nil value of device token when don't allow push notification alert ,so check some thing going nil on your side.